# Information about vehicle speed

Tags: veins, sumo

I was trying to stop my vehicle through this command in the .rou.xml file:

```
<vehicle id="vec1" type="G1" route="route0" depart="0" > 
     <stop lane="376643565#0_0" friendlyPos="false" duration="10"/>
</vehicle>
```

What I've noticed is that the vehicle correctly stops at that line for that time interval, but as soon as it starts travelling again, it doesn't follow the route0, but it comes back to the original position as well as the second vehicle which follows it, while all the other vehicles follow the normal route.

Why this happens? If I run the scenario from Sumo alone, then all vehicles follow the same given path, but in Veins they don't. May I have a flag or something set by default?

Update: I've tried a new path, in which there's a straight line and it works. While the one which is not working is in proximity of a roundabout
Thanks

Comment: Are you programmatically changing the route of the vehicle? The Veins demo simulation is doing this whenever a message is received.

Comment: @ChristophSommer No, I haven't. They all should follow route0